# Loading and unloading widget on wordpress site - possible css error?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am developing a science wordpress website and I am having an issue with a widget. When I load the page the widget quickly loads and then disappears.

This only happens in Chrome and Firefox, and not Explorer for some reason.

It is EXTREMELY strange as this widget was working perfectly for a while, and after changing nothing it stopped. I have disabled all plugins and it still does not work. I even restored my website from a backup when it was for sure working -- still nothing.

A page of the website with the issue (just dummy content) is located here: 
http://scientized.com/physics-astronomy/

As one can see it quickly loads the image slider:
[image]

Then unloads the image slider:
[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: it appears the problem is intermittent. Please refresh a few times to replicate it if you don't see the error on the first load.